# For what use cases might one choose tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rather than prepareForSegue:sender:?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I understand the differences between `tableVIew:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Furthermore, both can be used to display a new view when a cell is tapped. Are there use cases where might one choose `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` rather than `prepareForSegue:sender:`? If so, what are those use cases?

Comment: not sure if this is an example of what you're looking for, but i don't use storyboards, so i don't use `prepareForSegue`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` was available in iOS from the start; `prepareForSegue:` has only been available recently, with the whole StoryBoard architecture.  Thus, these days, `prepareForSegue:` is preferred.

Note that the actual segue function is `prepareForSegue:sender:`. When a `UITableViewCell` initiates the segue the `sender` will be the selected cell.  Thus you've got everything available as you would in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Also, segues are used when transitioning to another view controller.  If your app won't have a cell selection transition to a view controller, then you can't use a segue.  For example, if a cell selection, in your app, is going to do something with animation or directly with views, you'd use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Except that you still need to use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in a dynamic table view because the segue's can not be configured in the storyboard.  This is one of the use cases where you would still use it.

Comment: That is not correct; I just tried it in Xcode.  A UITableView configured with 'DynamicPrototypes' allowed a segue connection from the cell to a (detail) view controller.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I was trying to get different segue's from different rows when I "decided" that it wasn't possible.  It does make sense that you can do this, thanks for testing it to make sure!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the incomplete selector name. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use the 'old way'. Why? Because I'm used to it, and it makes sense to me. It was available from the start.

`prepareForSeque:`, on the other hand, was added recently. Most people that have use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the past are used to it, it works, and, besides, *if it ain't broke don't fix it!*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a UITableView where the rows are dynamic, you will want to invoke your segue in  tableVIew:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

If you look at the screenshots for my iPad app, for example, I dragged out each segue from the static cell.

https://itunes.apple.com/ml/app/h4-spanish-lite/id388918463?mt=8#

Unfortunately, now I want to have French and Chinese language apps.  I don't currently have a conjugator for French and it doesn't apply to Chinese.  Also, some of the games don't work in Chinese.  So, now I need to dynamically create my table.  I could create separate storyboards but that seems like a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

With `tableVIew:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you're getting the selected item. At the time you know the selected item you can call `prepareForSegue:` to set up the next `UIViewController` designed by the use of Storyboard, e.g. initialize some properties.

Edit: You just use `prepareForSegue:` if you're using Storyboard, available since iOS 5